# Policy to allow user to view secrets at 1 sub-tree but not others in hashicorp vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

I have a secrets engine in vault called "root" with 3 subtrees of "apps", "ops" & "test". I'm trying to create an ACL policy that will allow specific users to only see a certain subtree. I have a sample policy set for "apps" users to only see their subtree:

```
path = "root/*" {
  capabilities = ["list"]
}
path = "root/data/apps*" {
  capabilities = ["list", "read"]
}
path = "root/metadata/apps*" {
  capabilities = ["list", "read"]
}
path = "root/data/ops*" {
  capabilities = []
}
path = "root/metadata/ops*" {
  capabilities = []
}
path = "root/data/test*" {
  capabilities = []
}
path = "root/metadata/test*" {
  capabilities = []
}
```

As a note, root is a KV2 engine and we are currently running vault version 1.12.2

The above works as intended, as I can view/read all secrets in the "apps" subtree - my only concern is that I can still view secrets in the "ops" & "test" subtrees. Based on the policy above, I get the following window below for the other 2 subtrees:
[image: vault_view_secret]

I know this is a result of the first item in the policy that allows view all for everything under root, however this window still gives the pretext of being able to see secrets in the other subtrees (if you know the path) though you still get an access denied, even if the submitted path is correct. I don't remember seeing this window in older versions of vault (I think i did the same test in 1.8.3) and am wondering if this is something new that we have to deal with it or if there is a proper policy setting that will not access to the other subtrees.

FYI - if i remove the "list" setting at the root, then even when navigating to the "apps" subtree it gives me the same window. If the explicit entries for the other subtrees are removed, then I can navigate those trees but get access denied to read them (still not desired)...

Long story short, just want to know if I can give access to the "apps" subtree and essentially hide the other 2 subtrees. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can accomplish this with explicit denies, and by removing the `list` permission for all paths at `root`:

```
path = "root/data/apps*" {
  capabilities = ["list", "read"]
}
path = "root/metadata/apps*" {
  capabilities = ["list", "read"]
}
path = "root/data/ops*" {
  capabilities = ["deny"]
}
path = "root/metadata/ops*" {
  capabilities = ["deny"]
}
path = "root/data/test*" {
  capabilities = ["deny"]
}
path = "root/metadata/test*" {
  capabilities = ["deny"]
}
```

You can additionally use the wildcard operator as the list element in the policy:

```
path = "root/data/apps*" {
  capabilities = ["list", "read"]
}
path = "root/metadata/apps*" {
  capabilities = ["list", "read"]
}
path = "root/*/ops*" {
  capabilities = ["deny"]
}
path = "root/*/test*" {
  capabilities = ["deny"]
}
```

Default permission is also `deny`, and therefore they can be omitted entirely to the same effect:

```
path = "root/data/apps*" {
  capabilities = ["list", "read"]
}
path = "root/metadata/apps*" {
  capabilities = ["list", "read"]
}
```

As the primary concern here is viewing secret paths available from the `root` mount path in the Vault UI, this will remove that capability in the UI while still preserving the desired capabilities.

Comment: I agree with your answer above, however my problem is having the "list" capability at the root level causes the "View Secret" window above to appear for the "ops" & "test" subtrees. If I remove it from the policy, then that same window appears at the root level which is definitely not ideal.

Comment: @Probius I understand your objective better now; updating answer.

Comment: So if I try your suggestion using the implicit **deny** and only use the explicit allows, I then get the "View Secret" (screenshot above) window at the top level of the root - which is not desired. Maybe this is something with the new versions of the UI that wasn't there in older versions.

Comment: @Probius the UI would always allow an arbitrary secret path input; I thought you wanted to not enable users with this policy to view the existence of the other secret paths (which this policy enforces).

Comment: alright i think i understand now... it has been sometime since i've messed with the ACL policies in vault so if the UI is going to allow an arbitrary secret path input then that's fine for now. i'll go with your suggestion and see how the users feel with that. thanks!!